# Efficient way to group data.table results by year

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for advice as to whether I am using `data.table` efficiently.

I have a data set which describes incidents, with one row per incident. On each row I have the date of the incident. Right now I just want to count how many incidents there are per year. I have done this using the code below, but it feels inefficient. I would appreciate any advice on how to improve this. (The data set is far bigger than shown below and I also have to do other similar, but more complex counts)

Create a list of dates from 2000 until end 2012:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("1/1/2000", format="%d/%m/%Y"), 
  as.Date("31/12/2012", format="%d/%m/%Y"), 
  "day")

# Choose one million occurrences on various dates:    

sampleDate <- sample(dates, 1000000, replace=TRUE)

# Create `data.table`, one line per incident:   

library(data.table)
DT.dt <- data.table(Date=sampleDate, incident=1)

# Time how long it takes to count the number of indidents in each year: 

system.time(result <- DT.dt[,count(format(Date,"%Y"))])

user  system elapsed 
11.83    0.10   11.95 

result[1:3,]
x    freq
2000 76930
2001 77101
2002 76666
```

So it works (I think) but I suspect there is a more efficient solution...

Comment: Not sure where the function `count` comes from. The `data.table` way would be: `DT.dt[, .N, by=format(Date, "%Y")]`. And I've a feeling that this Q might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are doing aggregate operations (grouping) with `data.tables`, *especially* for large data sets, you should set the field you are grouping by as a `key` (using `setkeyv(DT, "your_key_field")`, etc...). Also, I can't speak definitively on the topic, but generally I think you will get better performance from using native `data.table::` functions / operations within your `data.table` object than you would when using other packages' functions, like `plyr::count` for example. Below, I made a few `data.table` objects - the first is identical to your example; the second adds a column `Year` (instead of calculating `format(Date,"%Y")` at the time of function execution), but sets `Date` as the `key`; and the third is the same as the second, except that it uses `Year` as the `key`. I also made a few functions (for benchmarking convenience) that do the grouping in different ways.

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr) # for 'count' function
library(microbenchmark)
##
dates <- seq.Date(
  from=as.Date("2000-01-01"),
  to=as.Date("2012-12-31"),
  by="day")
##
set.seed(123)
sampleDate <- sample(
  dates,
  1e06,
  replace=TRUE)
##
DT.dt <- data.table(
  Date=sampleDate,
  incident=1)
##
DT.dt2 <- copy(DT.dt)
DT.dt2[,Year:=format(Date,"%Y")]
setkeyv(DT.dt2,"Date")
##
DT.dt3 <- copy(DT.dt2)
setkeyv(DT.dt3,"Year")
##
> head(DT.dt,3)
         Date incident
1: 2003-09-27        1
2: 2010-04-01        1
3: 2005-04-26        1
> head(DT.dt2,3)
         Date incident Year
1: 2000-01-01        1 2000
2: 2000-01-01        1 2000
3: 2000-01-01        1 2000
> head(DT.dt3,3)
         Date incident Year
1: 2000-01-01        1 2000
2: 2000-01-01        1 2000
3: 2000-01-01        1 2000

## your original method
f1 <- function(dt)
{
  dt[,count(format(Date,"%Y"))]
}
## your method - using 'Year' column
f1.2 <- function(dt)
{
  dt[,count(Year)]
}
## use 'Date' column; '.N' and 
## 'by=' instead of 'count'
f2 <- function(dt)
{
  dt[,.N,by=format(Date,"%Y")]
}
## use 'Year' and '.N','by='
f3 <- function(dt)
{
  dt[,.N,by=Year]
}
##
Res <- microbenchmark(
  f1(DT.dt),
  f1.2(DT.dt2),
  f1.2(DT.dt3),
  f2(DT.dt2),
  f3(DT.dt3))
##
> Res
Unit: milliseconds
         expr        min         lq     median         uq      max neval
    f1(DT.dt) 478.941767 515.144253 557.428159 585.579862 706.8724   100
 f1.2(DT.dt2)  98.722062 115.588034 126.332104 137.792116 223.4967   100
 f1.2(DT.dt3)  97.475673 118.134788 125.836817 136.136156 238.2697   100
   f2(DT.dt2) 352.767219 373.337958 387.759996 429.301164 542.1674   100
   f3(DT.dt3)   7.912803   8.441159   8.736887   9.685267  76.9629   100
```

**Observations:**

1. Grouping by the precalculated field `Year` instead of calculating
   `format(Date,"%Y")` at execution time was a definite improvement -
   for both of the `count` and `.N` approaches. You can see this by
   comparing the `f1()` and `f2()` times to the `f1.2()` times.
2. The `count` approach seemed to be a little slower than the `.N` & 'by=' approach (`f1()` compared to `f2()`.
3. The best approach by far was to use the precalculated field `Year` and the native `data.table` grouping `.N` & `by=`; `f3()` was considerably faster than the other four timings.

There are some pretty experience `data.table` users on SO, certainly more so than myself, so there may be an even faster way to do this. All else aside, though, it's definitely a good idea to set a `key` on your `data.table`; and it certainly seems like you would be much better off precalculating a field like `Year` than doing so "on the fly"; you can always delete it afterwards if you don't need it by using `DT.dt[,Year:=NULL]`.

Also, you said you are trying to count the number of `incident`s per year - and since your example data had `incident = 1` for all rows, counting was the same as summing. But assuming your real data has different values of `incident`, you could so something like this:

```
> DT.dt3[,list(Incidents=sum(incident)),by=Year]
    Year Incidents
 1: 2000     77214
 2: 2001     77385
 3: 2002     77080
 4: 2003     76609
 5: 2004     77197
 6: 2005     76994
 7: 2006     76560
 8: 2007     76904
 9: 2008     76786
10: 2009     76765
11: 2010     76675
12: 2011     76868
13: 2012     76963
```

(where I called `setkeyv(DT.dt3,cols="Year")` above).

Comment: Small note. There is no need to set key for aggregation operations. We prefer *adhoc by*. And your benchmarks should include the time to `setkey`.

Comment: I know post rules say I must not say thanks.  But I have no reputation so I can't even vote up your answer.  But this is amazing.  Thanks!